# Difference between PassKeys and using touch-id to login in Apps

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, biometrics, passkey

[PassKeys](https://fidoalliance.org/passkeys/) is a new way to sign-in to web-apps and mobile apps by FIDO alliance.
I looked at it and could understand how it works; However, I'm unable to understand difference from using touch-id to login (biometrics login ?) which many of the banking and other applications already support (ex: [1Password](https://support.1password.com/touch-id-ios/)).

For PassKeys, this is my understanding:

- involves PKI;
- private key stored in the device's key chain
- public key stored on server
- during login, server sends challenge encrypted with the public key
- client side access the device's key-chain using the biometrics data (touch-id, face-id), signs the challenge and responds to server
- login succeeds

How does ***login with touch-id*** works and what sort of *keys* & *secrets* are stored and where?